# How to set proxy so that Software-updater works in 18.04?

Tags: updates, 18.04, proxy

I've tried setting env variables, proxy setting via network settings dialog but nothing worked so far. Prev Ubuntu releases were free from this problem. Also, developers please fix proxy settings for once and for all.

Comment: Did you also try this: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/ ?

Comment: @Jos 's link contains the solution! Worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Software Updater and Aptitude don't use the HTTP proxy environment variables. They load all configuration files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

Create a new configuration file named `proxy.conf` using a text editor (I used Pluma):

```
sudo pluma /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Add the following lines to set your proxy configuration:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
```

Save your changes and exit the text editor.
Now your proxy settings will be applied even to Software Updater and you can update your packages.

Source: [Jos's link](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/)