# Unable to software updates for Ubuntu 18.04, showing error as Network is not available. But, I am able to access websites from browser

Tags: networking, updates, proxy

I have loaded Ubuntu 18.04 in my office PC. Network is configured with manual IP,Subnetmask,Gateway and DNS. Also, we have Proxy server in the office . Proxy server IP and Port are configured.

Now, I am able to access to all the websites from browser.

But, I am unable to do software updates 1) either from terminal (sudo apt-get update) or 2)by using GUI software update option available in Ubuntu 18.04.

It is showing Network is unavailable.

I have also tried by going to Icon "software & updates" -> "Ubuntu Software" tab and selecting download from "main server" option. This also didn't work for me.

But,I am able to access to all the websites from browser.

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [How to set proxy so that Software-updater works in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063522/how-to-set-proxy-so-that-software-updater-works-in-18-04)

```
    Ubuntu Software Updater and Aptitude don't use the HTTP proxy environment variables. They load all configuration files under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d.

Create a new configuration file named proxy.conf using a text editor (I used Pluma):

sudo pluma /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
Add the following lines to set your proxy configuration:

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
Save your changes and exit the text editor. Now your proxy settings will be applied even to Software Updater and you can update your packages.
```

Comment: Thank you. For our proxy server no username and password. Our proxy server is 10.34.2.192 and port:7118. Now, what is to be typed at "user" , "password". Do I need to replace "proxy.server" with  10.34.2.192